# NaN issue when dealing with live output

Tags: nan

I am a newbie to coding and I am currently having some issues with some numbers I want to display. I have an input type='range' slider and I would like to display live output of the number selected but the live output just turns up as NaN.

```
<div id='tierslider'>
    <form oninput="x.value=parseInt(tierslider.value)">
           <span>500</span>
           <input type='range' min='500' max='5000' value='500'>
           <span>5000</span>
           <output id='tierslider2' name='x'></output>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the id 'tierslider' attribute placed wrong. It needs to be placed for input element

```
<form oninput="x.value=parseInt(tierslider.value)">
       <span>500</span>
       <input type='range' id='tierslider' min='500' max='5000' value='500'>
       <span>5000</span>
       <output id='tierslider2' name='x'></output>
</form>
```